# Couldn't match expected type ‘IO a0’ with actual type ‘a1 -> IO ()’

Tags: haskell

Works:

```
enumerate = \todos ->
    setSGR [SetColor Foreground Vivid Red] >>=
    (\_ -> putStrLn $ unlines $ map transform todos) >>
    setSGR [Reset]
```

Doesn't work:

```
enumerate = \todos ->
    setSGR [SetColor Foreground Vivid Red] >>
    putStrLn . unlines . map transform todos >>
    setSGR [Reset]
```

As far as I can undestand, `>>=` passes on the variable, which is then ignored in the subsequent lambda `(\_ -> ...)`. However, when I transform that to using `>>` and have function composition, it doesn't appear to work.

What is the difference between the two that causes the second not to compile? It'd be great to know why those two expressions aren't equivalent.

```
/Users/atimberlake/Webroot/HTodo/htodo/app/Main.hs:18:25:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘IO a0’ with actual type ‘a1 -> IO ()’
    In the second argument of ‘(>>)’, namely
      ‘putStrLn . unlines . map transform todos’
    In the first argument of ‘(>>)’, namely
      ‘setSGR [SetColor Foreground Vivid Red]
       >> putStrLn . unlines . map transform todos’
    In the expression:
      setSGR [SetColor Foreground Vivid Red]
      >> putStrLn . unlines . map transform todos
      >> setSGR [Reset]

/Users/atimberlake/Webroot/HTodo/htodo/app/Main.hs:18:46:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘a1 -> [String]’
                with actual type ‘[[Char]]’
    Possible cause: ‘map’ is applied to too many arguments
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘map transform todos’
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely
      ‘unlines . map transform todos’
```

Comment: Disagree with the close vote. This is not a typographical error, but a misunderstanding of how `.` and `$` work.

Comment: Agreed... Think it will be useful for other starting out in Haskell. In truth I should have realised, but when dealing with the complexities of Haskell, it's common to make these silly mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
enumerate = \todos ->
    setSGR [] >>
    (putStrLn . unlines . map transform) todos >>
    setSGR []
```

Note that `f . g . map h xs` implies that `map h xs` is a function you are composing with `g` and then `f`. But `map transform todos` is a list, and
you are really composing the function `putStrLn`, `unlines` and `map transform` and then applying the composition to the list `todos`.

In general:

```
f $ g $ h x  = (f . g . h) x
```

so your working expression:

```
putStrLn $ unlines $ map transform todos
```

is the same as:

```
( putStrLn . unlines . map transform ) todos
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense now. Thank you!